# change link to logout when user login

Tags: node.js

I want to change login button to logout when `ctx.session.userID` have value, I try to use ejs engine, but it didn't work.

I use console.log to print `userid` after login, but it shows `undefined` on terminal even it being assigned value in `login()`.

This is server.js:

```
const M = require('./model')
const Koa = require('koa')
var serve = require('koa-static')
const session = require('koa-session')
var KoaRouter = require('koa-router')
var koaLogger = require('koa-logger')
const koaBody = require('koa-body')
const views = require('koa-views')
var app = new Koa()
const router = new KoaRouter()
app.use(views('view', {map:{html:'ejs'}})) 
app.use(koaLogger())
app.use(koaBody())
app.use(router.routes())
app.use(serve(__dirname + '/public'));
app.keys = ['*@&))9kdjafda;983'] 
const CONFIG = { 
  key: 'd**@&(_034k3q3&@^(!$!',
  maxAge: 86400000
}
app.use(session(CONFIG, app)) 
router
.get('/', async (ctx) => {
    let title = 'ejs test'
    let userid = ctx.session.userID
    console.log('ctx.session.userID:',userid) // print userid after login, but it shows undefined
    await ctx.render('index',{
        title, userid
    })
})

.post('/login', login)

.get('/error', async (ctx)=> {
    await ctx.render('error',{})
})

async function login(ctx){
    let {id, password} = ctx.request.body
    console.log("test:",id,password)
    if ( await M.get(id,password) != null){
        ctx.session.userID = id
        ctx.redirect('/')
        console.log('login success')
    }
    else {
        ctx.redirect('/error')
    }
}
```

And this is a part of index.html:

```
            <% if (userid == null){ %>
            <a href="/login">Login</a>   
            <% } else { %>
            <a href="/logout">Logout</a>
            <% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi If user is not logged in by default it will store undefined.

you need to check if user id is defined or not -

```
<% if (userid === undefined){ %>
<a href="/login">Login</a>   
<% } else { %>
<a href="/logout">Logout</a>
<% } %>
```

Hop this helps.